# Weird bug involving Samsung Galaxy S2 and a jQuery Mobile Application

Tags: jquery, mobile

**Hey there**

Recently i've been working on a web application running on the jQuery Mobile framework. It's been working great for the last couple of weeks but whenever i test the thing on our Samsung Galaxy S2 test phone. A really strange bug popped up.

Whenever i run through the first step of the application (Entering search terms) and press 'search' the application searches for results. Displays them for the user. Then 2 seconds later, it ***removes every div containing a search result***. Now this of course is a application breaking bug in it's own sense. But the weird thing is, if i search from anywhere else in the application but the frontpage, it doesn't remove the search results. Which is weird, cause the buttons call the exact same functions.

The application runs great on any other platform i've tested on.

Has anyone ever encountered such a problem with the Galaxy S2? (HTML elements randomly getting removed)

Comment: A wild guess - maybe the search is fired again and searches for nothing? You didn't specify how your application works so the problem will be kinda hard to identify.

Comment: @Przemek If that were to be the case, it would fire the 'loading' screen aswell. unfortunately, that is not the case.

Comment: what version of jquery mobile are you using? There seems to be an issue that was closed just a few days ago: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3723, I've had a similar problem so I'm just switching to using latest instead and hopefully it will work - http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js